# Guzzle http get single value from json array

Tags: php, json, guzzle

So i currently am getting the json array response :

{"state":"TO_BE_CREATED","btc_amount":0.1,"btc_dest_address":"1FhnVJi2V1k4MqXm2nHoEbY5LV7FPai7bb","uuid":"xmrto-YHxJap"}

This is my php code:

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();
$data   = [
    "btc_dest_address"    => '1FhnVJi2V1k4MqXm2nHoEbY5LV7FPai7bb',
    "btc_amount"          => '0.1'
];

$result = $client->post('https://xmr.to/api/v2/xmr2btc/order_create/', ['json' => $data]);


print "<pre>";
print_r( $result->getBody()->getContents() );
print "</pre>";
```

But i want to get only a specific value from that json which would be for example uuid , how could i do this ?

Comment: it is not duplicate as it does not work with guzzle

Comment: What does not work?! You can print the result (as we can see in your question), why wouldn't you be able to put that output into `json_decode()`?

Comment: @Gongas `json_decode()`, a native PHP function, does not work with Guzzle?

Comment: not the way we use with native php it would return null,  matt already answered what i needed

Comment: The question I supplied as a duplicate does exactly what matt does in their answer, as in it shows you how you can use `json_decode()`. You'll have to do a bit of thinking yourself to get it working.

Comment: @TomUdding Early congrats on 2k rep :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you just need to use `json_decode` to turn it into an object you can use:

```
$data = json_decode($response->getBody());
echo $data->uuid;
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: thanks alot man, this is what i needed

Comment: No problem.  If it's a working solution for you, mark it as answered so others know as well.

Comment: I just did bud, thanks